# Need help solving $\;\arcsin(\sqrt3\sin x)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help solving $$\arcsin\left(\sqrt3\sin x\right)=1$$

I've tried substituting various x's in, but not exactly sure what it means to find x fitting to the arcsin.

Comment: Could you, please, add parentheses to the formula ? It is not very clear for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have 
$\sqrt3\sin x=\sin1\implies\sin x=\dfrac{\sin1}{\sqrt3}$

$$x=n\pi+(-1)^n\arcsin\dfrac{\sin1}{\sqrt3}$$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to solve for $x$:

$$\arcsin\left( \sqrt{3}\sin x\right)=1$$
$$ \sqrt{3}\sin x=\sin 1$$
$$\sin x = \frac{\sin 1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$x=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin 1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + 2n\pi$$
for any integer $n$.

Don't think there's a nicer way of doing it...

Answer (score 2):

When you have $x$ in the $\arcsin$ function, you need to find $\sin$ of whole equation:
$$\arcsin(\sqrt3\sin x)=1$$
$$\sin(\arcsin(\sqrt3\sin x))=\sin(1)$$
$$\sqrt3\sin x=\sin1$$
$$\sin x=\dfrac{\sin1}{\sqrt3}$$
$$\sin x=\dfrac{\sqrt3\sin1}{3}$$
Now find $\arcsin$ of whole equation to get $x$:
$$\arcsin(\sin(x))=\arcsin\left({\dfrac{\sqrt3\sin1}{3}}\right)\cdot(-1)^k+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x=\arcsin\left({\dfrac{\sqrt3\sin1}{3}}\right)\cdot(-1)^k+k\pi$$